# Skipping worksheets without IF statements

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code here but I'd like it to skip worksheets names `Aggregated`, `Collated Results`, `Template`, `End`. I have tried to add an `If` statement in to skip these but it doesn't seem to like it.

```
Sub FillBlanks()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Set rng2 = ws.Range("L1:AB40")

        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng1 = rng2.SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
        on error goto 0

        if not rng1 is nothing then
            Application.Iteration = True
            rng1.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-1]C,R[1]C)"
            Application.Iteration = False
            rng2.Value = rng2.Value
        end if    
    Next ws 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show how you tried the `If` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the names of the sheets you want to skip to the line `worksheetsToSkip = array("...` (below), then the code below should skip said sheets.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillBlanks()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Dim worksheetsToSkip As Variant
    worksheetsToSkip = Array("Aggregated", "Collated Results", "Template", "End")

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, worksheetsToSkip, 0)) Then
             Set rng2 = ws.Range("L1:AB40")

             On Error Resume Next
             Set rng1 = rng2.SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
             On Error GoTo 0

            If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
                 Application.Iteration = True
                 rng1.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-1]C,R[1]C)"
                 Application.Iteration = False
                 rng2.Value = rng2.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```